# OpenCV Linear SVM not training

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

I've been stuck on this for some time now. OpenCV's SVM implementation doesn't seem to work for a linear kernel. I'm fairly sure there's no bug in the code: when I change the `kernel_type` to RBF or POLY, keeping everything else as is, it works.

The reason I say it doesn't work is, I save the generated model and check it out. It shows support vector count as 1. Which is not the case in RBF or POLYnomial kernels.

There's nothing special about the code in itself, I've used OpenCV's SVM implementation before, but never a linear kernel. I tried setting the `degree` to 1 in a POLY kernel and it results in the same model. Which makes me believe something is buggy here.

The code structure, if required:

```
Mat trainingdata;    //acquire from files. done and correct.
Mat testingdata;     //acquire from files. done and correct again.
Mat labels;          //corresponding labels. checked and correct.

SVM my_svm;
SVMParams my_params;
my_params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
my_params.kernel_type = SVM::LINEAR;    //or poly, with my_params.degree = 1.
my_param.C = 0.02;    //doesn't matter if I set it to 20000, makes no difference.

my_svm.train( trainingdata, labels, Mat(), Mat(), my_params );
//train_auto(..) function with 10-fold cross-validation takes the same time as above (~2sec)!
Mat responses;
my_svm.predict( testingdata, responses );
//responses matrix is all wrong.
```

I have 500 samples from one class and 600 from the other class to test, and the correct classifications I get are: 1/500 and 597/600.

Craziest part:
**I have done the same experiment with the same data on libSVM's MATLAB wrapper, and it works.** Was just trying to do an OpenCV version of it.

Comment: Are you sure the data's linearly separable? The fact that it works with fancier kernels strongly suggests non-linearly separable data... Are you training libSVM using linear kernels?

Comment: Do you know the formulation of SVM? There should be difference when you set C to 0.02 or 20000. Be sure that you set it correctly. It can't be same for all parameters. Also you should set epsilon parameter to 0.001, the default is something else AFAIK. One last thing, what happens when you run `train_auto()` instead of `train()`?

Comment: Try adapt standard example examples/cpp/points_classifier.cpp there is also svm classifier. I've checked it, and it worked.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I duplicated the experiment from what I did in libSVM. It works like a charm there.

Comment: @guneykayim I'm aware of the formulation of SVM and I understand what C does to the model. Which is why I find it surprising that the value of C is not making _any_ difference at all. `train_auto()` does nothing at all. Gives me C=1. I tried.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov that's new; I hadn't heard of it. I'll try it and get back.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug that you always get only one support vector with **linear CvSVM**.

OpenCV optimizes a linear SVM down to one support vector.
The idea here is that the support vectors define the classification margin, and to do the actual classification only the separating hyperplane is needed and it can be defined by only one vector.

Parameter **C** doesn't matter if your training data is linearly separable. Maybe it is your case.

Comment: I don't understand how a separating hyperplane _needs_ only one support vector. And besides, I've used linear SVMs previously and gotten a number of support vectors (which works well with the ideas of overfit and generalisation).

Comment: And `C` would be useful in cases where noise would affect a classification; the presence of noise is not a huge assumption (at least in this case).

Comment: When svm is training it is using some amount of support vectors which lie on the margin or inside it (if we use “Soft” margin). But when opencv stores trained classifier - the only information it needs is only one vector (normal to the hyperplane), that defines discriminating hyperplane. http://www.songho.ca/math/plane/plane.html

Comment: Yes, *C* is useful if we have noise. But if we have no noise and data is linearly separable then *C* won't affect training.

Comment: Oh yes, I agree. I don't recall `nSV` for this experiment, but I'm sure I've seen numbers greater than one.